# Video is not visible but audio works fine in iOS, flutter video player

Tags: flutter

This works fine in android device both audio and video is playing accordingly. But in the case of iOS, only audio work and there are no visuals.
I'm running the app in the iOS simulator. I also searched for the issue on GitHub where people suggested that it will work fine on a real device but it isn't.

**Here is my whole code which plays video**

```
class UiPathVideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  UiPathVideoPage({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _UiPathVideoPageState createState() => _UiPathVideoPageState();
}

class _UiPathVideoPageState extends State<UiPathVideoPage> {
  VideoPlayerController _controller;
  ProgressDialog pr;
  @override void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState


    super.initState();




    if(widget.text == 'Telecom') {
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recycler-view-8483d.appspot.com/04ea5f9ca1')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
          setState(() {});
          _controller.value.isPlaying
              ? _controller.pause()
              : _controller.play();

        });
    }
    if(widget.text == 'Finance'){
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recycler-view-8483d.appspot.com/o/VideoLibrary%273320d38f')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
          setState(() {});
          _controller.value.isPlaying
              ? _controller.pause()
              : _controller.play();
        });

    }
    if(widget.text == 'Sales'){
      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recycler-view-8483d.appspot.com/o/VideoLibraryc498e')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
          setState(() {});
          _controller.value.isPlaying
              ? _controller.pause()
              : _controller.play();
        });

    }

    if(widget.text == 'Others'){

      _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/recycler-view-8483d.appspot.com/o/VideoLibrary%2Fcea5f9ca1')
        ..initialize().then((_) {
          // Ensure the first frame is shown after the video is initialized, even before the play button has been pressed.
          setState(() {});
          _controller.value.isPlaying
              ? _controller.pause()
              : _controller.play();

        });

    }

  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pr = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pr.style(
        message: 'Please Waiting...',
        borderRadius: 10.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        progressWidget: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        elevation: 10.0,
        insetAnimCurve: Curves.easeInOut,
        progress: 0.0,
        maxProgress: 100.0,
        progressTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
        messageTextStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)
    );
    return Container(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
          title: Text(""),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child:
            _controller.value.initialized
                ? AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
            )
                : Container(
              child: Image.asset('assets/loading.gif'),
            )

        ),


        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {

              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**I'm looking for help, Thanks in advance**

Comment: Please add code, and not the screenshots of the code

Comment: did you found any solution? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: any solution found? please update.

Comment: Any solutions? Facing same issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue final my problem was vp9 video codec that not supported by IOS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34839426)